# Chakra UI for React: change _focus borderColor not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I set the default theme on Chakra UI for React with `extendTheme()`.
When I try to change the Select component's style like this, the `_focus` style does not applied, while the `color` behaves as expected.

##### Refs

- [Chakra-UI Style Props](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/features/style-props#pseudo)
- [How to change the  placeholder color globally?](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/discussions/3783)

#### Captions

[image]

[image]

#### Codes

index.ts

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { Select } from './select';

export const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: {
    brand: '#008561',
    brandLight: '#00b485',
  },
  components: {
    Select,
  },
});
```

select.ts

```
export const Select = {
  parts: ['field'],
  baseStyle: ({ colorMode }: any) => ({
    field: {
      color: 'brandLight',
      _focus: {
        borderColor: colorMode === 'dark' ? 'brandLight' : 'brand',
      },
    },
  }),
  sizes: {},
  variants: {},
  defaultProps: {},
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the focus border color, you have to access the `focusBorderColor` selector,

This can either be set in the `variant` you want to change, or in the `defaultProps` selector of your component theme.

```
defaultProps: {
  focusBorderColor: 'gray.500',
},
```

Another workaround I have seen, is to set the global shadows to a chakra color, note that any color you define, can also be accessed like the example below

```
const colors = { mycolor: "#F39C12" }

const shadows = {
  outline: '0 0 0 3px var(--chakra-colors-mycolor-500)',
};

const theme = extendTheme({ config, colors, styles, components, shadows });
```

Workaround was found here: [Chakra-UI Issue-663](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/663#issuecomment-1002234205)

Hope this helps your project

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
 _focusVisible={{
      outline: "none",
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
`const baseStyle = definePartsStyle({ field: { _focusVisible: { 'border-color': '#F16821 !important', 'box-shadow': '0 0 0 1px #F16821 !important' } } });`